# how to deploy a azure api app to private network

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I would like to use some of the benefits of hosting a web api in Azure, but I want that api to be private (not accessible from the outsite world) as it only be used internally.

I am not sure if that is even possible. I've tried deploying from visual studio but the api is hosted on xyz.azurewebsites.net and is accessible from everywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I like the idea of App Service Environment as it seems to be more robust, but also expensive. I'll go with levelnis answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could restrict access to the site to a specific ip address or range of addresses through the web.config. Add a section to `system.webServer`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="123.456.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0"/>
        </ipSecurity>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

More info here: [IP and Domain Restrictions for Windows Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to levelnis's suggestion about static ip security restricting access, there is the option of using an App Service Environment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-intro

> App Service Environments are ideal for application workloads
>   requiring:
>
> - Very high scale
> - Isolation and secure network access

An ASE is always placed in a virtual network's subnet, so you can use NSGs to control access. ASEs are a Premium service though so can be quite expensive.